# SVG is resizing inside a flex container, but I want the item to stay the same size

Tags: html, css, svg

I have three SVGs that have the same height, but different widths. I am trying to put them inside a flex container, and change the `flex-direction` into a column. My problem is that the smallest SVG is resizing bigger than the others. Making them not the same size.

```css
.selectionContainer {
  width: 50vw;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: left;
  gap: 6vh;
}

.aboutContainer {
  background-color: blue;
}

.galleryContainer {
  background-color: red;
}

.contactContainer {
  background-color: green;
}

#aboutOutline {
  width: 0;
  fill: white;
}

#galleryOutline {
  width: 0;
  fill: white;
}

#contactOutline {
  width: 0;
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="selectionContainer">
  <div class="aboutContainer">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 365 79" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <a class="selection About"href="#">
                <path id="aboutOutline" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M20.3387 77H0.0557861L39.3346 1.18184H59.2649L73.4068 77H53.7597L50.8517 59.7841H28.989L20.3387 77ZM18.4887 74H4.98867L41.1591 4.18184H56.7728L69.7955 74H56.2955L53.3874 56.7841H27.1389L18.4887 74ZM32.2434 46.625H51.6713L46.9205 18.5H46.375L32.2434 46.625ZM37.1082 43.625H48.1221L45.351 27.2201L37.1082 43.625ZM77.8524 77L90.4394 1.18184H119.71C125.028 1.18184 129.616 2.0138 133.279 3.89634C136.875 5.72259 139.57 8.33659 141.098 11.7908C142.605 15.1464 142.942 18.8518 142.27 22.785C141.729 25.9767 140.628 28.832 138.901 31.2733C137.264 33.5965 135.243 35.5134 132.851 37.0017L132.841 37.0081L132.831 37.0144C132.703 37.0927 132.574 37.1698 132.445 37.2456C132.626 37.3586 132.806 37.4755 132.984 37.5962C135.564 39.3449 137.461 41.787 138.707 44.7902C140.025 47.9449 140.244 51.5527 139.615 55.455L139.613 55.4673L139.611 55.4795C138.915 59.575 137.296 63.2824 134.767 66.56L134.76 66.5691C132.181 69.8843 128.73 72.4329 124.52 74.2624C120.256 76.1255 115.27 77 109.653 77H77.8524ZM123.323 71.5114C127.142 69.8523 130.164 67.5909 132.392 64.7273C134.619 61.8409 136.039 58.5909 136.653 54.9773C137.221 51.4546 136.982 48.4432 135.937 45.9432C134.892 43.4205 133.346 41.4659 131.301 40.0796C130.601 39.6053 129.877 39.2055 129.13 38.8802C128.603 38.6512 128.065 38.4591 127.515 38.3039C126.656 38.0613 125.767 37.9089 124.85 37.8466C124.75 37.8399 124.651 37.8342 124.551 37.8296L124.687 37.1478C126.206 36.7938 127.663 36.2916 129.057 35.6411C129.812 35.289 130.548 34.8935 131.267 34.4546C133.312 33.1818 135.039 31.5455 136.448 29.5455C137.88 27.5228 138.835 25.1023 139.312 22.2841C139.903 18.8296 139.585 15.7387 138.357 13.0114C137.153 10.2841 135.005 8.13639 131.914 6.5682C128.823 4.97729 124.755 4.18184 119.71 4.18184H92.9824L81.3915 74H109.653C114.971 74 119.528 73.1705 123.323 71.5114ZM121.011 53.5033L121.011 53.5007C121.271 51.9261 121.094 50.6748 120.624 49.6335L120.621 49.6266L120.618 49.6196C120.153 48.5773 119.39 47.7321 118.19 47.0689L118.177 47.0617L118.164 47.0543C117.005 46.3983 115.391 45.9773 113.164 45.9773H101.733L99.3475 60.4318H109.414C113.669 60.4318 116.37 59.6052 117.974 58.4095C119.728 57.0793 120.687 55.4769 121.011 53.5033ZM119.778 60.8068C117.437 62.5568 113.982 63.4318 109.414 63.4318H95.812L99.187 42.9773H113.164C115.755 42.9773 117.914 43.4659 119.642 44.4432C121.369 45.3978 122.607 46.7159 123.357 48.3978C124.107 50.0568 124.312 51.9205 123.971 53.9887C123.517 56.7614 122.119 59.0341 119.778 60.8068ZM121.749 27.3008L121.752 27.2977C122.641 26.2499 123.203 25.0086 123.422 23.4916L123.429 23.4452L123.437 23.3991C123.78 21.4556 123.357 20.2223 122.481 19.2723C121.686 18.4099 120.036 17.6137 116.71 17.6137H106.443L104.283 30.875H113.267C115.072 30.875 116.687 30.5486 118.149 29.9262C119.635 29.2801 120.817 28.4021 121.749 27.3008ZM100.755 33.875H113.267C115.448 33.875 117.471 33.4773 119.335 32.6818C121.221 31.8637 122.789 30.7159 124.039 29.2387C125.312 27.7387 126.096 25.9659 126.392 23.9205C126.869 21.2159 126.301 18.9887 124.687 17.2387C123.073 15.4887 120.414 14.6137 116.71 14.6137H103.892L100.755 33.875ZM195.926 73.4747L195.921 73.477C190.32 76.4629 184.277 77.9546 177.84 77.9546C171.111 77.9546 165.156 76.3826 160.114 73.1066L160.105 73.1007C155.039 69.783 151.425 65.044 149.247 59.0338L149.243 59.0234C147.067 52.9517 146.756 45.8597 148.085 37.8818C149.372 30.1407 151.918 23.3955 155.795 17.7268C159.637 12.1097 164.39 7.7565 170.054 4.73869C175.703 1.72957 181.802 0.227295 188.306 0.227295C194.995 0.227295 200.909 1.81338 205.909 5.11839C210.958 8.41832 214.545 13.1629 216.697 19.1907C218.896 25.2846 219.22 32.399 217.89 40.3994C216.604 48.1654 214.045 54.9163 210.139 60.5674C206.298 66.1346 201.56 70.4597 195.926 73.4747ZM207.669 58.8637C211.283 53.6364 213.703 47.3182 214.931 39.9091C216.203 32.25 215.851 25.6818 213.874 20.2046C211.919 14.7273 208.715 10.5341 204.26 7.62502C199.828 4.6932 194.51 3.22729 188.306 3.22729C182.283 3.22729 176.669 4.61366 171.465 7.38639C166.26 10.1591 161.863 14.1705 158.272 19.4205C154.681 24.6705 152.272 30.9887 151.044 38.375C149.772 46.0114 150.113 52.5568 152.067 58.0114C154.044 63.4659 157.272 67.6591 161.749 70.5909C166.226 73.5 171.59 74.9546 177.84 74.9546C183.794 74.9546 189.351 73.5796 194.51 70.8296C199.692 68.0568 204.078 64.0682 207.669 58.8637ZM199.359 26.124L199.357 26.1154C198.525 23.097 197.123 21.065 195.283 19.7435L195.276 19.7383L195.268 19.733C193.37 18.3526 190.939 17.5796 187.794 17.5796C184.367 17.5796 181.234 18.4292 178.337 20.1317L178.332 20.1349C175.472 21.8079 172.967 24.2968 170.846 27.7137C168.779 31.0803 167.299 35.2761 166.484 40.3821L166.48 40.4048L166.477 40.4275C165.615 45.3403 165.721 49.1954 166.573 52.1295C167.442 55.1237 168.871 57.1594 170.743 58.4938C172.673 59.8482 175.12 60.6023 178.249 60.6023C181.657 60.6023 184.769 59.7623 187.643 58.0811C190.505 56.4066 192.998 53.9278 195.095 50.5362L195.102 50.525C197.188 47.1826 198.689 42.9997 199.527 37.8924M169.01 60.9432C166.488 59.1478 164.715 56.4887 163.692 52.9659C162.669 49.4432 162.613 45.0909 163.522 39.9091C164.385 34.5 165.976 29.9091 168.294 26.1364C170.635 22.3637 173.476 19.5 176.817 17.5455C180.181 15.5682 183.84 14.5796 187.794 14.5796C191.453 14.5796 194.533 15.4887 197.033 17.3068C199.533 19.1023 201.272 21.7728 202.249 25.3182C203.249 28.8637 203.328 33.2159 202.488 38.375C201.601 43.7841 199.988 48.3637 197.647 52.1137C195.328 55.8637 192.499 58.7159 189.158 60.6705C185.817 62.625 182.181 63.6023 178.249 63.6023C174.613 63.6023 171.533 62.7159 169.01 60.9432ZM199.527 37.8899C200.324 32.9959 200.203 29.1175 199.362 26.1326L199.359 26.124M276.688 1.18184H295.418L287.271 50.2799C286.375 55.758 284.268 60.6347 280.937 64.849C277.652 69.0335 273.474 72.2858 268.458 74.6087L268.447 74.6138C263.398 76.9268 257.829 78.0568 251.788 78.0568C245.724 78.0568 240.404 76.9341 235.968 74.5218L235.957 74.5154C231.542 72.0886 228.263 68.6539 226.251 64.2313L226.248 64.2245L226.245 64.2177C224.251 59.7785 223.799 54.7642 224.691 49.311L224.692 49.3044L232.677 1.18184H251.407L243.43 49.2244C243.43 49.2259 243.43 49.2274 243.43 49.229C243.025 51.6988 243.234 53.714 243.896 55.3801C244.581 57.0235 245.672 58.3009 247.247 59.268C248.799 60.207 250.892 60.7728 253.697 60.7728C256.487 60.7728 258.902 60.212 261.005 59.151C263.16 58.064 264.887 56.6007 266.233 54.7524C267.582 52.8771 268.467 50.7268 268.873 48.253L268.874 48.2473L276.688 1.18184ZM268.663 56.5114C267.027 58.7614 264.924 60.5341 262.356 61.8296C259.788 63.125 256.902 63.7728 253.697 63.7728C250.493 63.7728 247.822 63.125 245.686 61.8296C243.572 60.5341 242.049 58.7614 241.118 56.5114C240.209 54.2387 239.993 51.6478 240.47 48.7387L247.868 4.18184H235.22L227.652 49.7955C226.834 54.7955 227.277 59.1932 228.981 62.9887C230.709 66.7841 233.515 69.75 237.402 71.8864C241.288 74 246.084 75.0568 251.788 75.0568C257.447 75.0568 262.584 74 267.197 71.8864C271.811 69.75 275.606 66.7841 278.584 62.9887C281.584 59.1932 283.493 54.7955 284.311 49.7955L291.879 4.18184H279.231L271.834 48.7387C271.356 51.6478 270.299 54.2387 268.663 56.5114ZM299.642 17.7841L302.418 1.18184H364.206L361.43 17.7841H339.854L330.036 77H311.408L321.226 17.7841H299.642ZM324.765 14.7841L314.947 74H327.492L337.31 14.7841H358.89L360.663 4.18184H304.958L303.185 14.7841H324.765Z"/>
            </a>
        </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="galleryContainer">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 465 78" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <a href="#" class="selection Gallery">
                <path id="galleryOutline" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M51.1517 29.75L50.8588 27.0768C50.706 25.6823 50.3912 24.5425 49.9608 23.6156L49.9473 23.5866L49.9345 23.5573C49.5302 22.6354 48.9961 21.9064 48.3397 21.3246L48.3255 21.3121L48.3116 21.2994C47.6548 20.7023 46.8152 20.2068 45.7332 19.8461C44.6727 19.4926 43.3456 19.2841 41.7046 19.2841C38.6608 19.2841 35.8325 20.0331 33.1705 21.5478C30.5492 23.0521 28.2498 25.2721 26.2946 28.3067L26.2897 28.3144C24.379 31.26 23.011 34.9613 22.2675 39.507L22.2653 39.5204C21.4896 44.1316 21.53 47.8325 22.2219 50.7227C22.9325 53.5971 24.1943 55.5543 25.8695 56.8568C27.568 58.138 29.8912 58.8978 33.0796 58.8978C36.0583 58.8978 38.631 58.373 40.8516 57.3879C43.0861 56.3739 44.8529 54.9809 46.2149 53.214L46.2209 53.2062L46.2269 53.1985C46.8127 52.4487 47.3138 51.6346 47.7269 50.75H33.2918L36.1265 33.6364H71.4413L69.3465 45.92C68.3008 52.4714 65.9853 58.2106 62.3402 63.054C58.7335 67.8465 54.2191 71.5436 48.8269 74.1163C43.4611 76.6872 37.6056 77.9546 31.3068 77.9546C24.3172 77.9546 18.2095 76.41 13.1473 73.1465L13.1398 73.1417L13.1324 73.1368C8.08953 69.8435 4.52321 65.1682 2.43265 59.2491L2.43009 59.2419L2.42758 59.2347C0.356716 53.2746 0.0514475 46.3815 1.31211 38.6748L1.31262 38.6717C2.2909 32.7305 4.04486 27.3617 6.60862 22.6005L6.61121 22.5956C9.17174 17.8611 12.326 13.805 16.0865 10.4623C19.8273 7.1372 23.9905 4.59175 28.5665 2.845L28.5715 2.8431C33.1651 1.09901 37.9467 0.227295 42.8978 0.227295C47.1407 0.227295 51.0684 0.848658 54.6448 2.14046C58.2045 3.39548 61.3179 5.20142 63.9351 7.58395C66.581 9.97181 68.5896 12.827 69.9412 16.1224C71.3249 19.4173 71.9406 23.0016 71.8399 26.8289L71.763 29.75H51.1517ZM61.9205 9.80684C59.625 7.71593 56.8637 6.1023 53.6364 4.96593C50.4319 3.80684 46.8523 3.22729 42.8978 3.22729C38.3069 3.22729 33.8864 4.03411 29.6364 5.64775C25.4091 7.26138 21.5568 9.61366 18.0796 12.7046C14.6023 15.7955 11.6591 19.5682 9.25003 24.0227C6.86367 28.4546 5.20458 33.5 4.27276 39.1591C3.06821 46.5228 3.39776 52.8864 5.26139 58.25C7.14776 63.5909 10.3182 67.7159 14.7728 70.625C19.25 73.5114 24.7614 74.9546 31.3068 74.9546C37.1932 74.9546 42.6023 73.7728 47.5341 71.4091C52.4887 69.0455 56.625 65.6591 59.9432 61.25C63.2614 56.8409 65.4091 51.5682 66.3864 45.4318L67.8864 36.6364H38.6705L36.8296 47.75H51.7876C51.5949 48.8009 51.3237 49.8009 50.9739 50.75C50.3949 52.3214 49.6005 53.7532 48.5909 55.0455C46.9091 57.2273 44.7387 58.9205 42.0796 60.125C39.4205 61.3068 36.4205 61.8978 33.0796 61.8978C29.3978 61.8978 26.3864 61.0114 24.0455 59.2387C21.7273 57.4432 20.1478 54.8409 19.3068 51.4318C18.4887 48.0228 18.4887 43.8864 19.3068 39.0228C20.1023 34.1591 21.5909 30.0455 23.7728 26.6818C25.9546 23.2955 28.5909 20.7159 31.6818 18.9432C34.7955 17.1705 38.1364 16.2841 41.7046 16.2841C43.5909 16.2841 45.25 16.5228 46.6819 17C48.1137 17.4773 49.3296 18.1705 50.3296 19.0796C51.3296 19.9659 52.1137 21.0568 52.6819 22.3523C53.2728 23.625 53.6591 25.0909 53.8409 26.75H68.8409C68.8537 26.2652 68.8537 25.7861 68.8409 25.3129C68.8267 24.7847 68.7966 24.2637 68.7505 23.75C68.5439 21.4449 68.0173 19.2858 67.1705 17.2727C65.9887 14.3864 64.2387 11.8977 61.9205 9.80684ZM86.8804 77H64.2925L103.053 1.18184H126.423L139.972 77H118.006L115.497 61.0796H94.7197L86.8804 77ZM85.0137 74H69.1955L104.889 4.18184H123.911L136.389 74H120.57L118.062 58.0796H92.853L85.0137 74ZM98.5268 46.5568H116.246L112.082 20.1364H111.536L98.5268 46.5568ZM110.46 29.1141L103.348 43.5568H112.736L110.46 29.1141ZM143.653 77L156.24 1.18184H177.082L167.536 58.8296H197.477L194.423 77H143.653ZM163.999 61.8296L173.544 4.18184H158.783L147.192 74H191.885L193.931 61.8296H163.999ZM200.522 77L213.109 1.18184H233.951L224.405 58.8296H254.346L251.292 77H200.522ZM220.868 61.8296L230.413 4.18184H215.652L204.061 74H248.754L250.799 61.8296H220.868ZM257.39 77L269.978 1.18184H323.112L320.058 19.3523H287.785L286.041 29.9887H315.919L312.865 48.1591H283.013L281.267 58.8296H313.703L310.649 77H257.39ZM277.736 61.8296L280.464 45.1591H310.327L312.373 32.9887H282.509L285.236 16.3523H317.52L319.566 4.18184H272.521L260.93 74H308.111L310.157 61.8296H277.736ZM318.572 77L331.159 1.18184H361.247C366.849 1.18184 371.726 2.1687 375.705 4.34301C379.708 6.5176 382.613 9.67896 384.275 13.7884C385.943 17.8308 386.261 22.4364 385.447 27.4677L385.446 27.4748L385.445 27.4819C384.601 32.5472 382.754 36.9999 379.848 40.7553C377.39 43.9565 374.304 46.5104 370.636 48.4231L381.521 77H358.782L349.646 52.25H343.547L339.413 77H318.572ZM341.007 49.25H351.737L360.872 74H377.168L366.837 46.8778C367.066 46.7849 367.294 46.6893 367.52 46.5909C368.223 46.2825 368.903 45.9517 369.56 45.5983C372.728 43.8946 375.366 41.6687 377.474 38.9205C380.043 35.6023 381.713 31.625 382.486 26.9887C383.236 22.3523 382.906 18.3296 381.497 14.9205C380.111 11.4887 377.702 8.84093 374.27 6.97729C370.861 5.11366 366.52 4.18184 361.247 4.18184H333.702L322.111 74H336.872L341.007 49.25ZM352.997 37.3864C355.815 37.3864 358.224 37 360.224 36.2273C362.224 35.4546 363.804 34.2955 364.963 32.75C366.145 31.2046 366.918 29.2841 367.281 26.9887C367.668 24.6477 367.531 22.6932 366.872 21.125C366.213 19.5341 365.02 18.3296 363.293 17.5114C361.565 16.6705 359.293 16.25 356.474 16.25H346.52L342.989 37.3864H352.997ZM346.532 34.3864H352.997C355.556 34.3864 357.578 34.0338 359.143 33.4289C360.678 32.8358 361.778 31.9972 362.563 30.95L362.572 30.9388L362.58 30.9277C363.405 29.8483 364.017 28.418 364.318 26.5193L364.32 26.5097L364.321 26.5001C364.65 24.5058 364.476 23.1674 364.107 22.2874L364.104 22.2803L364.101 22.2732C363.758 21.4472 363.143 20.76 362.008 20.2226L361.994 20.2157L361.979 20.2087C360.807 19.6379 359.033 19.25 356.474 19.25H349.06L346.532 34.3864ZM388.241 1.18184H411.302L421.239 28.4848L440.153 1.18184H464.16L428.168 50.513L423.741 77H402.999L407.57 49.6507L388.241 1.18184ZM410.667 49.3182L406.542 74H421.201L425.326 49.3182L458.258 4.18184H441.724L420.894 34.25H420.144L409.201 4.18184H392.667L410.667 49.3182Z"/>
            </a>
        </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="contactContainer">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 499 78" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <a href="#" class="selection Contact">
                <path id="contactOutline" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M71.6571 31.625H50.9749L51.0463 28.5553C51.0849 26.8924 50.8689 25.5487 50.4761 24.4684L50.4736 24.4617L50.4712 24.4549C50.0695 23.3335 49.4895 22.4322 48.742 21.7004L48.7308 21.6893L48.7196 21.6782C47.9944 20.953 47.0815 20.3746 45.922 19.9654L45.9036 19.9589L45.8853 19.9521C44.7233 19.5249 43.3431 19.2841 41.7046 19.2841C38.5045 19.2841 35.6189 20.0766 32.9839 21.6537C30.3482 23.2313 28.0564 25.5573 26.1378 28.7415L26.1333 28.7489C24.2362 31.8771 22.867 35.7564 22.097 40.4618L22.0963 40.466C21.342 45.035 21.4334 48.6002 22.167 51.2902C22.9112 54.0189 24.1493 55.8375 25.7441 57.0186C27.4053 58.2098 29.5823 58.8978 32.4659 58.8978C34.2982 58.8978 36.0106 58.6698 37.6142 58.2272C39.2295 57.7586 40.6678 57.1057 41.946 56.2792C43.2451 55.4312 44.3677 54.4104 45.3243 53.21L45.3331 53.1988L45.3421 53.1878C46.3008 52.0079 47.0577 50.6606 47.6074 49.1252L48.3194 47.1364H69.258L68.1421 50.974C67.1203 54.4877 65.5326 57.8514 63.4015 61.0617C61.2708 64.3059 58.64 67.191 55.5261 69.7164L55.5205 69.7209L55.5149 69.7254C52.3622 72.2576 48.792 74.2535 44.826 75.7224C40.774 77.2231 36.3824 77.9546 31.6818 77.9546C24.8697 77.9546 18.8426 76.3866 13.7351 73.1177L13.7294 73.1141C8.60854 69.8203 4.95469 65.0777 2.75018 59.0404C0.524031 52.9438 0.176724 45.7925 1.48169 37.7255L1.48295 37.7177L1.48425 37.7099C2.7937 29.877 5.37687 23.098 9.31353 17.4636L9.31504 17.4615C13.2283 11.8711 18.0301 7.56545 23.7237 4.61962L23.7284 4.61718C29.4086 1.69102 35.494 0.227295 41.9432 0.227295C46.3741 0.227295 50.4666 0.832613 54.1875 2.08965C57.9033 3.34499 61.1401 5.20362 63.8417 7.69428C66.5873 10.1815 68.6412 13.2254 70.0051 16.7767C71.3824 20.363 71.9423 24.3721 71.7704 28.7429L71.6571 31.625ZM60.8977 59.4091C62.251 57.3714 63.3594 55.2805 64.223 53.1364C64.6212 52.1477 64.9673 51.1477 65.2614 50.1364H50.4318C49.7727 51.9773 48.8523 53.625 47.6705 55.0796C46.5114 56.5341 45.1477 57.7728 43.5796 58.7955C42.0341 59.7955 40.3182 60.5682 38.4318 61.1137C36.5455 61.6364 34.5568 61.8978 32.4659 61.8978C29.0796 61.8978 26.25 61.0796 23.9773 59.4432C21.7273 57.7841 20.1591 55.3296 19.2727 52.0796C18.3864 48.8296 18.3409 44.7955 19.1364 39.9773C19.9546 34.9773 21.4318 30.7159 23.5682 27.1932C25.7046 23.6478 28.3296 20.9432 31.4432 19.0796C34.5568 17.2159 37.9773 16.2841 41.7046 16.2841C43.6364 16.2841 45.375 16.5682 46.9205 17.1364C48.4659 17.6818 49.7727 18.4887 50.8409 19.5568C51.9318 20.625 52.75 21.9205 53.2955 23.4432C53.757 24.7124 54.007 26.1444 54.0455 27.739C54.0525 28.029 54.0525 28.3243 54.0455 28.625H68.7727C68.8099 27.6811 68.8099 26.7619 68.7727 25.8674C68.7694 25.7864 68.7657 25.7056 68.7617 25.625C68.6217 22.7815 68.1026 20.1906 67.2046 17.8523C66 14.7159 64.2046 12.0682 61.8182 9.90911C59.4546 7.72729 56.5909 6.0682 53.2273 4.93184C49.8636 3.79548 46.1023 3.22729 41.9432 3.22729C35.9659 3.22729 30.3523 4.57957 25.1023 7.28411C19.875 9.98866 15.4318 13.9546 11.7727 19.1818C8.13637 24.3864 5.69319 30.7273 4.44319 38.2046C3.19319 45.9318 3.56819 52.5341 5.56819 58.0114C7.56819 63.4887 10.8296 67.6818 15.3523 70.5909C19.8977 73.5 25.3409 74.9546 31.6818 74.9546C36.0682 74.9546 40.1023 74.2728 43.7841 72.9091C47.4659 71.5455 50.75 69.7046 53.6364 67.3864C56.5227 65.0455 58.9432 62.3864 60.8977 59.4091ZM147.069 40.541L147.067 40.5504C145.734 48.3612 143.126 55.1266 139.168 60.7577C135.275 66.3277 130.472 70.6199 124.759 73.5633C119.095 76.4937 112.985 77.9546 106.474 77.9546C99.6653 77.9546 93.6247 76.3997 88.4794 73.1648L88.4737 73.1612C83.3082 69.8974 79.6028 65.1834 77.3467 59.167L77.3453 59.1632C75.0649 53.0569 74.7066 45.895 76.0362 37.8209C77.3226 29.9836 79.9068 23.1998 83.8695 17.5622C87.7843 11.9701 92.6084 7.65599 98.3416 4.6897C104.05 1.71338 110.196 0.227295 116.735 0.227295C123.506 0.227295 129.516 1.79702 134.639 5.05866C139.828 8.34774 143.533 13.0993 145.764 19.1623C148.043 25.2681 148.4 32.4394 147.071 40.5316L147.069 40.541ZM142.951 20.2046C140.928 14.7046 137.622 10.5 133.031 7.59093C128.462 4.68184 123.031 3.22729 116.735 3.22729C110.667 3.22729 104.997 4.60229 99.7239 7.35229C94.4511 10.0796 89.9852 14.0568 86.3261 19.2841C82.6671 24.4887 80.2239 30.8296 78.9966 38.3068C77.7239 46.0341 78.1102 52.6364 80.1557 58.1137C82.2011 63.5682 85.508 67.7387 90.0761 70.625C94.6671 73.5114 100.133 74.9546 106.474 74.9546C112.519 74.9546 118.156 73.6023 123.383 70.8978C128.633 68.1932 133.076 64.2387 136.712 59.0341C140.372 53.8296 142.838 47.5 144.11 40.0455C145.383 32.2955 144.997 25.6818 142.951 20.2046ZM126.412 26.9972L126.409 26.9852C125.703 24.2356 124.479 22.4035 122.882 21.2097C121.257 19.9951 119.087 19.2841 116.156 19.2841C112.957 19.2841 110.073 20.0757 107.439 21.6512C104.827 23.2272 102.545 25.5523 100.625 28.7378C98.7493 31.8648 97.3885 35.7681 96.617 40.5257L96.6152 40.5367L96.6133 40.5477C95.8376 45.1162 95.9089 48.666 96.6194 51.3287C97.3597 54.0178 98.6008 55.8249 100.218 57.0105C101.905 58.2078 104.109 58.8978 107.019 58.8978C110.207 58.8978 113.061 58.1228 115.647 56.5905C118.257 55.0351 120.522 52.7448 122.415 49.612C124.292 46.4815 125.664 42.575 126.457 37.8159C127.212 33.2678 127.132 29.7068 126.415 27.0091L126.412 26.9972ZM129.417 38.3068C128.576 43.3523 127.099 47.6364 124.985 51.1591C122.872 54.6591 120.269 57.3296 117.178 59.1705C114.11 60.9887 110.724 61.8978 107.019 61.8978C103.61 61.8978 100.758 61.0796 98.4625 59.4432C96.1898 57.7841 94.6102 55.3409 93.7239 52.1137C92.8602 48.8864 92.8375 44.8637 93.6557 40.0455C94.4739 35 95.9398 30.7159 98.0534 27.1932C100.19 23.6478 102.803 20.9432 105.894 19.0796C109.008 17.2159 112.428 16.2841 116.156 16.2841C119.588 16.2841 122.428 17.125 124.678 18.8068C126.928 20.4887 128.474 22.9659 129.315 26.2387C130.178 29.4887 130.213 33.5114 129.417 38.3068ZM225.314 1.18184L212.727 77H195.618L175.497 38.5765L169.088 77H148.247L160.834 1.18184H178.15L198.186 39.5844L204.537 1.18184H225.314ZM199.82 48.0909H199.24L176.331 4.18184H163.377L151.786 74H166.547L173.877 30.0568H174.422L197.434 74H210.184L221.774 4.18184H207.081L199.82 48.0909ZM228.12 19.3523L231.173 1.18184H294.599L291.545 19.3523H270.176L260.63 77H239.958L249.503 19.3523H228.12ZM253.041 16.3523L243.495 74H258.086L267.632 16.3523H289.007L291.052 4.18184H233.711L231.666 16.3523H253.041ZM296.674 77H274.086L312.847 1.18184H336.217L349.766 77H327.8L325.291 61.0796H304.513L296.674 77ZM294.807 74H278.989L314.682 4.18184H333.705L346.182 74H330.364L327.855 58.0796H302.647L294.807 74ZM308.321 46.5568H326.039L321.876 20.1364H321.33L308.321 46.5568ZM320.253 29.1141L313.142 43.5568H322.529L320.253 29.1141ZM425.657 31.625H404.975L405.046 28.5553C405.085 26.8924 404.869 25.5487 404.476 24.4684L404.474 24.4617L404.471 24.4549C404.069 23.3335 403.489 22.4322 402.742 21.7004L402.731 21.6893L402.72 21.6782C401.994 20.953 401.081 20.3746 399.922 19.9654L399.904 19.9589L399.885 19.9521C398.723 19.5249 397.343 19.2841 395.705 19.2841C392.504 19.2841 389.619 20.0766 386.984 21.6537C384.348 23.2313 382.056 25.5573 380.138 28.7415L380.133 28.7489C378.236 31.8771 376.867 35.7564 376.097 40.4618L376.096 40.466C375.342 45.035 375.433 48.6002 376.167 51.2902C376.911 54.0186 378.149 55.8371 379.743 57.0181C381.405 58.2096 383.582 58.8978 386.466 58.8978C388.298 58.8978 390.011 58.6699 391.614 58.2272C393.229 57.7588 394.667 57.1063 395.944 56.2803C397.244 55.4321 398.367 54.4109 399.324 53.21L399.333 53.1988L399.342 53.1878C400.301 52.0079 401.058 50.6606 401.607 49.1252L402.319 47.1364H423.258L422.142 50.974C421.12 54.4877 419.533 57.8514 417.402 61.0617C415.271 64.3059 412.64 67.191 409.526 69.7164L409.521 69.7209L409.515 69.7254C406.362 72.2576 402.792 74.2535 398.826 75.7224C394.774 77.2231 390.382 77.9546 385.682 77.9546C378.87 77.9546 372.843 76.3866 367.735 73.1177L367.729 73.1141C362.609 69.8203 358.955 65.0777 356.75 59.0404C354.524 52.9438 354.177 45.7925 355.482 37.7255L355.483 37.7177L355.484 37.7099C356.794 29.877 359.377 23.098 363.314 17.4636L363.315 17.4615C367.228 11.8711 372.03 7.56545 377.724 4.61962L377.728 4.61718C383.409 1.69102 389.494 0.227295 395.943 0.227295C400.374 0.227295 404.467 0.832613 408.187 2.08965C411.903 3.34499 415.14 5.20362 417.842 7.69428C420.587 10.1815 422.641 13.2254 424.005 16.7767C425.382 20.363 425.942 24.3721 425.77 28.7429L425.657 31.625ZM415.818 9.90911C413.455 7.72729 410.591 6.0682 407.227 4.93184C403.864 3.79548 400.102 3.22729 395.943 3.22729C389.966 3.22729 384.352 4.57957 379.102 7.28411C373.875 9.98866 369.432 13.9546 365.773 19.1818C362.136 24.3864 359.693 30.7273 358.443 38.2046C357.193 45.9318 357.568 52.5341 359.568 58.0114C361.568 63.4887 364.83 67.6818 369.352 70.5909C373.898 73.5 379.341 74.9546 385.682 74.9546C390.068 74.9546 394.102 74.2728 397.784 72.9091C401.466 71.5455 404.75 69.7046 407.636 67.3864C410.523 65.0455 412.943 62.3864 414.898 59.4091C416.251 57.3714 417.359 55.2805 418.223 53.1364C418.621 52.1477 418.967 51.1477 419.261 50.1364H404.432C403.773 51.9773 402.852 53.625 401.67 55.0796C400.511 56.5341 399.148 57.7728 397.58 58.7955C396.034 59.7955 394.318 60.5682 392.432 61.1137C390.545 61.6364 388.557 61.8978 386.466 61.8978C383.08 61.8978 380.25 61.0796 377.977 59.4432C375.727 57.7841 374.159 55.3296 373.273 52.0796C372.386 48.8296 372.341 44.7955 373.136 39.9773C373.955 34.9773 375.432 30.7159 377.568 27.1932C379.705 23.6478 382.33 20.9432 385.443 19.0796C388.557 17.2159 391.977 16.2841 395.705 16.2841C397.636 16.2841 399.375 16.5682 400.92 17.1364C402.466 17.6818 403.773 18.4887 404.841 19.5568C405.932 20.625 406.75 21.9205 407.295 23.4432C407.757 24.7124 408.007 26.1442 408.045 27.7388C408.052 28.0288 408.052 28.3242 408.045 28.625H422.773C422.81 27.6811 422.81 26.7619 422.773 25.8675C422.769 25.7865 422.766 25.7056 422.762 25.625C422.622 22.7815 422.103 20.1906 421.205 17.8523C420 14.7159 418.205 12.0682 415.818 9.90911ZM431.632 19.3523L434.686 1.18184H498.111L495.057 19.3523H473.688L464.143 77H443.47L453.016 19.3523H431.632ZM456.553 16.3523L447.008 74H461.599L471.144 16.3523H492.519L494.565 4.18184H437.224L435.178 16.3523H456.553Z"/>
            </a>
        </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

What can I do to to have the "about" have automatic padding on the right so the svg can change into the correct size??

I have tried to change the `flex-grow` property with no luck. Also have attempted to use `flex: 1 1 0` with no luck as well. Nothing changed for both attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have succesfully solved the issue. The way I solved it was pretty simple, I just changed the viewbox of all the SVG into the same size. Since the size of the entity inside the viewbox isn't affected by the viewbox's size, the SVG is now technically all the same size, so the flexbox does not have to resize the SVG accordingly. here is what the solved code looks like
[image: solved result]

and here is the code. I changed all the elements of the svg to have the same width, and same height.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 78" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

Answer (score 0):

All you might have to do is add height to `svg`

```css
.selectionContainer svg {
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: By adding that, the SVG size is now static if I understand correctly. which is not what I want.

Comment: could you add an image to what you expect the images to be set like, do you expect it to be responsive based on resolution